# Can't login with Facebook through device/omniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I've created a login page with Devise and OmniAuth. I signed up using my email adres and a password and I can log in with that information. But when I log in through Facebook on my application I get redirected back to the login page [http://localhost:3000/login#*=*](http://localhost:3000/login#_=_)

This is the error log.

```
Started GET "/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-31 09:33:21 +0200
(facebook) Request phase initiated.

Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAyweq-3J1vtAAEvGsFRdMyYYmINmo3q9FIzEmpsNToJRUAQziwWc6wNL9OSvQILgivigd5M231b7efzz6_TGWL4jWviNZVNAov4KW99CBS5DrnAotLRyO2N9UfhJfpvHqyrsFwD_jmB13dRP-FMhiRz_bTyYjEzhQRq35RE7RyyJQvgSPHV0BiEyRBCUOWnMi3KWnhgYEJNyaweIqcjnqlPT47Uo3tXWsySQjd_Ifla9LzSdKbBsNkJuhT3afglrbyv_9nkWrq6Bo5xXgWMzE21o1EZF8rXz46VhiS9kzq4Xi69wdO82tjgDk2rCiWTazmdUBHm07OyElc2nc9C1TF&state=aac57855d6bebbf1a92cbd1ecb946489c308b1d21d749e15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-31 09:33:22 +0200
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQAyweq-3J1vtAAEvGsFRdMyYYmINmo3q9FIzEmpsNToJRUAQziwWc6wNL9OSvQILgivigd5M231b7efzz6_TGWL4jWviNZVNAov4KW99CBS5DrnAotLRyO2N9UfhJfpvHqyrsFwD_jmB13dRP-FMhiRz_bTyYjEzhQRq35RE7RyyJQvgSPHV0BiEyRBCUOWnMi3KWnhgYEJNyaweIqcjnqlPT47Uo3tXWsySQjd_Ifla9LzSdKbBsNkJuhT3afglrbyv_9nkWrq6Bo5xXgWMzE21o1EZF8rXz46VhiS9kzq4Xi69wdO82tjgDk2rCiWTazmdUBHm07OyElc2nc9C1TF", "state"=>"aac57855d6bebbf1a92cbd1ecb946489c308b1d21d749e15", "provider"=>"facebook"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-31 09:33:22 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 44.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have `http://localhost:3000/` set as my adres in the developer tool on Facebook.

My routes.rb
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  get 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'
  get 'login/show'
  get 'frontpage/show'

  get 'example' => 'example#index'

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'frontpage#show'
    match '/sessions/user', to: 'devise/sessions#create', via: :post
  end

  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
   where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
     user.provider = auth.provider
     user.uid      = auth.uid
     user.email    = auth.info.email
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
   end
  end
end
```

And my session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/frontpage/show'
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

And my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on but you're getting a 401 unauthorized from facebook. Which may mean your not passing the right parameters.

Comment: @Derrick: I don’t think that is a 401 _from Facebook_, but rather from his own login callback URL, `/auth/facebook/callback?code=…`